# What is the meaning of "surf couches"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs, slang

Today I read a blog and find the below sentence:

> I surf couches now and then ...

But I don't know the meaning, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the blog that contains this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couch surfing, or: "I surf couches." Means sleeping on a friend's sofa and then moving to another friend's place to sleep on their couch.

> couch-surf (from Google Dictionary)
>
> verb informal
>   gerund or present participle: *couchsurfing*
>
> 1 - stay temporarily in a series of other people's homes, typically making use of improvised sleeping arrangements.
>
> "many people were left homeless last year and have been couch surfing ever since with parents or friends"
>
> 2 - engage in sedentary activities such as watching television or browsing the Internet.
>
> "the bottom of this laptop does not get hot at all so you can put it in your lap and couch surf easily"

It is also the name of a group: [Couchsurfing: Meet and Stay with Locals All Over the World](http://www.couchsurfing.com).  You meet people online and they arrange to sleep on your sofa, rather than at a hotel.

Comment: Actually, the group couchsurfing.com does not allow members to charge anyone to stay at their home. They must offer their couch, extra bed, sleeping mattress, hammock, etc.  *for free*. (It is part of the group's by-laws.)

Comment: Part of the *unwritten rules* of the organization is that a good guest offers something in return for the free stay, usually in the form of a gift or some service, such as cooking the host a meal, etc. But direct giving of cash is not really allowed.

Comment: In the days before the "couchsurfing" phenomenon - which erupted about a decade ago, with broadband internet making it possible to network in such a way - the phrase had already been around for some decades, in its now secondary meaning as lazing around in front of the TV. Not the answer to this question, but it's always interesting to see how language changes over time, and some words get hijacked with new meanings.